# Petite mère, je cherche le sens et le contexte d'utilisation

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, littérature

Est-ce que c'est convenable d'appeller une amie par petite mère, l'expression est trop utilisée dans une traduction française du roman Les pauvres gens de Dostoïevski ?

Comment: J'ai souvent entendu l'expression affectueuse "petit père / petite mère" en s'adressant à un enfant en bas âge dont l'aspect pataud et bonhomme peut rappeler celui d'une personne âgée. Mais pas pour qualifier une amie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Une traduction du roman de Dostoïevski *Les pauvres gens* utilise en effet ***petite mère*** pour traduire ***маточка*** alors que d'autres traductions reprennent la translittération française ***matotchka***.

---

**Texte original russe** :

[image]

---

**Traduction de Victor Derély** (1888) :

[image]

---

**Traduction de Sylvie Luneau** (2005):

[image]

---

Ces deux traductions de маточка ont chacune leur mérite, *petite mère* indique la signification du mot russe alors que *matotchka* laisse au lecteur le choix de son interprétation.

On trouve quelques autres mots repris du russe très similaires, ***[baboushka](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))*** cité par [Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53577/1109), *[matouchka](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)* par [Roger Vadim](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53579/1109), et aussi ***[mamouchka](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)*** et ***[matriochka](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)***.

Quant à savoir si c'est convenable, la question n'a pas de sens pour son utilisation par Dostoïevski, c'est simplement ce que le personnage écrit.

S'il s'agissait d'un échange de courrier dans un contexte français, je ne vois pas pourquoi quelqu'un ne pourrait pas utiliser *petite mère* en s'adressant à une amie, spécialement si elle a des enfants mais ***petite maman*** serait plus affectueux.

Comment: À mon avis il s'agit plutôt de suffix "chka/tchka",  assez générique pour former des diminutifs avec le sens "petit qqch" - plus que quelques mots. Mais dans ce cas on parle de terms qui ont pris le sens indépendant, comme "petit enfant" ou "belle mère" en français (qui ne sont pas forcément particulièrement petit ou belle). Je le dit comme un locuteur de russe, mais je n'ai pas de connaissance linguistique particulaire à ce sujet

Comment: @RogerVadim Wikipedia décompose ce mot comme ceci: *Корень: -мат-; суффикс: -очк; окончание: -а.*

Comment: Ça semble correct - le "-a" final marque le cas nominatif, il n'est pas conservé en flexions.

Answer (score 5):

"petite mère" est souvent utilisé pour traduire "baboushka" qui indique respect et affection pour une mère ou une grand-mère.

Dans les textes d'auteurs français, le terme est plutôt utilisé pour une jeune mère (ou une grande soeur jouant le role de maman).

Je n'ai jamais entendu personne utiliser cette expression dans le langage courant. S'adresser ainsi à une femme serait plutôt mal accepté.

Answer (score 4):

*Matouchka* (матушка) et *batouchka* (батюшка) sont grammaticalement les diminutifs de *mère* et *père* en russe (il s'agit de termes un peu anciens). C'est pourquoi ils sont souvent traduits par *petite mère* et *petit père*. Néanmoins, la valeur sémantique de ces expressions est assez différente, signifiant plutôt le respect et la tendresse. Ironiquement, ça leur donne parfois la valeur de grandeur, comme l'exemplifient les expressions traditionnelles utilisées pour adresser la famille royale : *matouchka Imperatritsa* (матушка Императрица) = *ma petite mère l'Impératrice* ou *batouchka Tsar* (батюшка Царь) = *mon petit père le Czar*.

Answer (score 1):

> J'ai souvent entendu l'expression affectueuse "petit père / petite
> mère" en s'adressant à un enfant en bas âge dont l'aspect pataud et
> bonhomme peut rappeler celui d'une personne âgée. Mais pas pour
> qualifier une amie. ([Guillaume31](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53576/petite-m%C3%A8re-je-cherche-le-sens-et-le-contexte-dutilisation#comment113986_53576) en commentaire sous licence CC BY-SA)